# Determine remaining subgraphs after removal of a node joining them

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

So I ran into this problem while attempting to implement a feature:

Suppose I have a random, undirected graph of nodes, some of which are connected to each other.

Let's call every group of nodes that are reachable from each other to each other along some path a set.

Now, let's assume the graph contains only one such set (i.e., every node is reachable from every other node).

If I take a random node A and remove it from the set, I need to quickly and efficiently determine which sets remain.  If A is a cut-point in the set, then removing it should split the set into two or more smaller sets.  I simply need an efficient way of doing two things:

- Removing A from a set and determining remaining sets, and
- Adding a new node, B, with any number of new edges connecting it to other nodes.

I need to be able to perform both operations moderately quickly.  In essence, I'm looking for a O(log(n)) or a O(1) solution.  An O(n) solution is not acceptable, since this graph may be large.  I'm not particularly concerned with memory overhead.  Can anyone point me in the right direction with which data structure/algorithm to use here?  I've thought about things like Union-Find and Djikstra already, but they don't suit my needs. I don't want to run a full connectivity check on the entire graph every time a node is added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good [paper by Henzinger and King](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.2661). I think that it answers your question directly.

This method has amortized O(log^3(n)) complexity per deleting an edge (deleting a vertex is equal to deleting all edges incident to it) and O(log(n) / loglog(n)) worst case complexity per query (are v and u in the same connected component).

In addition, there are presented many variants of this problem e.g. you can do it faster if  only deleting is allowed.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alex I haven't implemented this particular graph algorithm, but here are a couple things to watch out for. First, log^3 n may look a lot better than sqrt n on paper, but the crossover point ignoring constants is around half a billion. It's worth considering previous efforts with worse asymptotic running times. Second, the authors claim a "small constant factor" but IME, since they use Euler-tour trees, that should be read as "we aren't in Robertson–Seymour territory" rather than "this is practical". Finally, you may get better results from an algorithm with no worst-case guarantee.

Comment: Thanks.  Right now I'm still reading through the paper.  I've never even heard of ET-trees until now.  By chance, is there a specific name for the problem I'm trying to solve?  Maybe the paper mentions it though, I've been skipping around.  I'll definitely take the crossover into consideration, as soon as I figure out what other approaches exist to solving this. -edit-: I believe the problem is called something like finding a fully dynamic algorithm for maintaining connectivity?

Comment: Ah ok, the paper's citations provide some other solutions as well.  This is a good find.

Comment: @Alex the name of your problem is Fully Dynamic Graph Connectivity